# ElasticSearch delete in Java

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch

I'm trying to delete all records with "lastRefresh" fields older that 1 hour from the current time in ES. I am getting a parse error in SOAP UI (HTTP 400, SearchPhaseExecutionException), but it does not make sense to me. I have verified that my date code is working, but being new to ES, I'm sure I made a rookie mistake somewhere... Below is my code in Java and what I get from the debugger to try and test in SOAP UI.:

```html
    RangeFilterBuilder range = FilterBuilders.rangeFilter(LAST_REFRESH_FIELD);      
      DateTime expiredLimit = DateTime.now().minusHours(1);      
      range.from(0);
      range.to(expiredLimit.getMillis());
      
      FilteredQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(), range);
      
      DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder deleteRequest = elasticClient.prepareDeleteByQuery(INDEX_NAME);
      deleteRequest.setQuery(query);
      DeleteByQueryResponse response = deleteRequest.execute().actionGet();
     
      if (response.status() == RestStatus.OK)
      {
         result = true;
      }
      else
      {
         log.info("deleted record was not found.");
      }
```

```html
{
  "filtered" : {
    "query" : {
      "match_all" : { }
    },
    "filter" : {
      "range" : {
        "lastRefresh" : {
          "from" : 0,
          "to" : 1429129890507,
          "include_lower" : true,
          "include_upper" : true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is I neglected to remember that I am using Zulu time (UTC), and I am in the Eastern Time Zone.  I was testing with bad data...